# map a 2d array array to produce leaflet.js markers

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, leaflet

Hi I'm having some trouble generating my markers in leaflet js. I have an object which has multiple entries per year. I want to create a layer group for each year that can be switched on and off. But i've hit a sticking point, I cant quite figure out how to map only the entries that match the parent array. IE 2016 == 2016.year...

My trouble is not being able how to map the second level items. The object is like this:

```
{
    "2016": [
        {
            "year": 2016,
            "latitude": 50.9500019,
            "longitude": 6.4836722
        },
        {
            "year": 2016,
            "latitude": 50.9500019,
            "longitude": 6.4836722
        }
    ],
    "2017": [
        {
            "year": 2017,
            "latitude": 50.9500019,
            "longitude": 6.4836722
        }
    ]
}
```

and the code is this:

```
const getGroupMarkers = (array, groupName) => Object.keys(array).map(function(keys, value){
    array[keys].map(createMarkers.bind(groupName));
});
```

This works to a degree but it returns all the years not just 2016.

Here's a pen of what I'm working on. Line 270 for the function in question.
https://codepen.io/sharperwebdev/pen/gvEQXe?editors=0010

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm scratching my head a bit with this one.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example of how you want the data to look like after transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with bracket notation. array[requiredEntry].map(callback);